# Flask-SQLAlchemy: How to make multiple one-to-one relationships between the same classes?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

How do you make multiple a one-to-one relationships between the same classes?

For example, I want to have a class "Location" which has two different type of "LoadDetail" which I have named "pickup_details" and "delivery_details". Can someone explain?

Here is what I so far-

```
class Location(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    pickup_detail = db.relationship("LoadDetail", foreign_keys='LoadDetail.pickup_id', backref='pickup_location')
    delivery_detail = db.relationship("LoadDetail", foreign_keys='LoadDetail.delivery_id', backref='delivery_location')

class LoadDetail(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    pickup_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
    delivery_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set the [primaryjoin](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/relationships.html#relationship-primaryjoin) of the relationship.  The example in the documentation sounds almost exactly like what you're trying to do.